# Azure Live Streaming RTMP with CDN

Tags: azure, streaming, rtmp

Previously I'm using Amazon AWS, now I'm moving to Microsoft Bizspark program which can use azure for free for certain limitation. I'm new to azure, and I want to setup RTMP live streaming with CDN. I'm using FlowPlayer in my website and OBS software to broadcast my live stream. Can I use Azure CDN with RTMP live streaming ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services supports ingesting live feeds using RTMP and uses Dynamic Packaging to dynamically transmuxe live streams for delivery in MPEG-DASH, Microsoft Smooth Streaming, Apple HLS, or Adobe HDS formats.

You can use [Azure Media Player](http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/) and [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm) instead of Flow Player and OBS Software. You can follow [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/18/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/) to setup the live streaming.